# Generalized Bessel Equation?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, bessel-functions

This seems like a long shot, but is there any closed form solution to 
$$y''x^{2r} - {\frac{r}{2}}y'x^r - cyx^{\frac{5r}{2}} = 0 ?$$

Here, we can take $x>0,r>0$ if it helps. This sort of looks like some kind of generalized Bessel equation... but not quite?

Comment: Is $c>0$ (or an eigenvalue)? What's your domain? Do you have initial or boundary conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Assume $c,r\neq0$ for the key cases.

This is an very complicated ODE.

Some special cases:

$r=1$ :

$x^2y''-\dfrac{xy'}{2}-cx^\frac{5}{2}y=0$

ODE of the form http://eqworld.ipmnet.ru/en/solutions/ode/ode0209.pdf and can transform to Bessel ODE.

$r=2$ :

$x^4y''-x^2y'-cx^5y=0$

$x^2y''-y'-cx^3y=0$